# How Can I Set Object from Dictionary to String Value to Update View Text Field?

Tags: ios, dictionary, nsstring, textfield

I have a value which I am pulling from a `CFDictionaryRef` as you see here:

```
CFDictionaryRef GPS = (CFDictionaryRef)CFDictionaryGetValue((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(mutableMetadata), kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary);
    NSDictionary *gps_dict = (__bridge NSDictionary*)GPS;
    NSLog(@"gps_dict: %@",gps_dict);
```

I then pull the `latitudeValue` from the dictionary values.  I have declared `latitudeValue` as and `NSString` property in the header file and synthesized it `@implementation`:

```
  latitudeValue = [gps_dict objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
```

At this point I would like to take the value for `latitudeValue` and have it update the text field on the view.  The text field is titled `latValue` and has been connected as an `IBOutlet` in the header file.  I have tried quite a few variations of `latValue.text = latitudeValue;` but they all cause thread errors when I run the program.  What is the best way for me to make this connection?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[gps_dict objectForKey:@"Latitude"]` is probably a *number* object (and not a *string*).

Therefore you should declare `latitudeValue` as `NSNumber` property, and then:

```
latValue.text = [latitudeValue stringValue];
```

or better

```
self.latValue.text = [self.latitudeValue stringValue];
```

using the property accessors. (Note that you don't have to @synthesize properties 
explicitly with the current compiler versions.)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer!  It definitely works now.  I am not sure why, but xcode made me change it to `self->latValue.text = [self.latitudeValue stringValue];` I will have to research the `.` syntax versus `->`